# Multiple canvases in OpenLayers 3

Tags: canvas, openlayers-3

I am creating a timeline for a map with multiple feature animations rendered on the canvas. I would like to create a timeline for these animations using LineStrings and Points, and sync the timeline with the other feature animations which are running using requestAnimationFrame. My timeline would ideally be rendered in a canvas, but not the OpenLayers' canvas that can pan and zoom. The timeline canvas would ideally be in a div with fixed positioning anchored to the bottom of the browser window.

Is this possible and if so, how would I approach it?

Comment: When you are saying timeline, you mean a control that lets you change the current time of the animation (similar to the control in the bottom left corner of this [map](http://inbo.cartodb.com/u/lifewatch/viz/754a87d0-a633-11e4-8c96-0e0c41326911/public_map)? And you want to use a canvas to render this control and are wondering how to place the canvas in the map?

Comment: Not a control, but another canvas within an HTML div element that I can create another Openlayers layer in. The purpose for putting a different canvas into a separate HTML div element would be so that I can position it (in this case fixed to the bottom of the browser window, and overlapping the underlying canvas which the map is on). My timeline consists of a long horizontal line (which could be made from a LineString geometry) and 12 tick marks (which could be made from Points).

Comment: Or is it possible to have one canvas for the 2D context and another for the 3D context. This has come up in my current project.